# DB2 9.5 + drop indexes + tablespaces = not pages reduced

Tags: db2

I am using DB2 v9.5, the database is not automatic storage and table spaces are all SMS (I know that SMS is not the best practice, but I'm studying to perform the migration then).

I dropped a total of 144 indexes, which were not used, but the amount of pages used/allocated in the database did not change after the DROP INDEX.

As far as I remember, for SMS tablespaces, if DROP of objects (tables or indexes), REORGs not be necessary, unless you had just deleted rows from the table, where it would be necessary to run the REORG to reduce the size allocated for the table .

Some opnion of what can be done to actually free the space from the indexes that were dropped?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you check "the amount of pages used/allocated" both before and after you drop indexes?

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure you had your indexes in SMS tablespaces, you should look in the corresponding filesystem, e.g. with `df -h` or some such.

Comment: Hi, in result of "df -h" not reduced too! :(

Comment: Then your indexes were in another tablespace, more likely. Or they didn't use any pages.